# Why is there a MOSFET here?

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge

On the TI [`DRV8703-Q1`](https://www.ti.com/product/DRV8703-Q1) H-bridge, there's a `MODE` pin to select the control interface.

What's the purpose of the MOSFET highlighted in yellow?
If it's for overvoltage protection, why not a Schottky diode?

[image: The MODE pin schematic]

You have my thanks

Comment: https://adl.ipe.kit.edu/downloads/DAS_2020_Text_7_English.pdf Page 1 has possible explanations. Might at least get you started down the path of figuring it out.

Comment: Any details missed?

Comment: Thanks for sharing @jpnine9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Perhaps a better answer is to compare using diodes](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgTCAMB0l3AWAnC1b0DYQEZvQKz4AcCYJ%20YA7NkZRpSPpDs04wKYC0uAUAGYgAzBXBEiIBHFHjmefFFhgeAdwlTsSCJOZhJOHgHM1zBIK1SECGVB4AlYzk0PsGZm7VDogqD5j4VDlTmOnqQPABODoKQCA6mELLwSQHa4HoIGLG6bgHCENmBoTwAzkIiZOJ5ae7MfACGADbF7ClS0bEZse3gPAAOEpnVA10xOL48AC6MdEKjGLqzsbK%20XiSURJB0SERIkJkuLMwAJuz1AK4NExEg812CWLcSZj7YSfCGNwvxnx1W46r4GbdQFYII2VSPCo-cCUBIBEEwiCQ2E2eyQhaPDQJHx6QReXwKfwQhZgDEklHYAIkcSk2LUxH6ez02kgelYgm4-E1AhUv5Q5kosJGenfEV-HKRemCe6sv7fRJvMJHWU0sQqoQyiAnc6XPo3NVgjBqszLHLErpgZhGyqWnrmhnWhlhVTMtVIbD5NXO9XSrDuiC%20nr9f3SEAhwPYcbYfBIMMep4QcMkHy216K97R2OO76OwTJnQK9NhTPDBOlvNLcCF9PXTpCZN1wPVsKRXPJ3My6vXJOxcOdw7vVSpb51%20UBR45tVjl1y54h6fQwOPE3g-WVGW523exsyxujMKWhhWEyQcT4eOScSxBp1ABG7AaPEPIEoo0vL93p4kIBv98fz80K8vyQVw1CvH87wfJ9NhfN81UoXcpwgv87Fgjo1XoLQQLGCA03AAh8PkNweUkbx8EsUtMMYMgcUoAB9TI6MgOjJG2Oj8CY6BsDo7g6MpUhvAQFEyFYGgYVjMIBLXRYX2IWZvEksBvE0ZgV22bxBDEsIAA8hAWMxY2EdctBwCAADUJgAHQARzkHgAHsfEGEwiAwLAiK4l4HJwSNBiwKw3MYBRIxC7yMUrALQQImBI1wnggA) for low currents in this application with a 3V3/100k load with a BJT diode and or a diode.  The flat line of switching loads < 20 uA of the FET tells you why this is good for OFFSET with variable low currents <= the current rated for Vt aka Vgs(th).  It is a crude but fairly stable reference for this purpose and cheaper than a bandgap reference diode to make.

Below I use a clock and ideal analog switch to show the difference in voltage for load = 10M and 100k. Ideally, the voltage drop on the FET is constant and equals the Vgs(th), here = 1.5V.

[image]

The Nh FET has some known Vt=Vgs(th) @ 50 uA or similar with some tolerance voltage range that produces a **constant offset voltage** below DVDD=3.3 +0.2/-0.3.  Thus this is sensitive to actual Vt and near rated currents for Vgs(the) in fact Vds=Vt , **like a Zener at very low currents.** but with wider tolerances, which is common for FETs Vgs(th) @ Id=x uA.

I expect the mean of the "window detector" defined as; . 0.75 V and < 1.35 V =(0.75+1.35)/2=1.05 V

Thus valid logic levels with hysteresis may be detected or the mid-range for some purpose. ( I admit not to reading the specs.)

### Why do they use this method to make a 2.23V Zener from Vgs(th)?

Perhaps, it was convenient to use the same CMOS logic used elsewhere for an analog purpose and thus almost free with suitable tolerances to provide hysteresis for 3.3V analog CMOS comparators. They can also detect 3 logic states at the input. <0.75, >1.35 and 0.75< x < 1.35.

### Reverse engineer this design as follows;

The two resistors give a ratio of about 71% which means Vt may be estimated with a mean value of two comparators of 1.05V.  The Vds drop = Vt from 3.3 should drop to 1.05V. Using KVL, 1.05 V = 71%( 3.3 - Vt) thus Vt = 2.23 V nom.

It is quite possible for thermal compensation that the comparators use a Vref using the same FET OFFSET voltage method and also provides reverse polarity protection.

Comment: Ok, so if I understood correctly: the designer wanted a Zener diode to do some voltage protection and voltage regulation. Instead of using a diode, they used the body diode of a MOSFET. At the same time, the MOSFET is always ON creating a voltage regulator. The two effects combined together create a Zener Diode using only a MOSFET.

Comment: I think they used 2 comparators. One with a 1 diode drop=Vref, another with a 2 diode drop=Vref2, so to balance a given tristate input MODE logic SPEC to work optimally with the lowest cost, they used GAIN and OFFSET to achieve that with the same Logic parts used elsewhere for free Thus  OFFSET = MOSFET Vds =  Vgs = Vgs(th), because that's what happens when the gate is tied to drain. just like diode references in Op Amps are NPN with base tied to the collector. There the base diode doesn't take all the current so it is more constant. Using a real zener would cost more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the added clarification and the image. It has helped greatly.

Comment: If Vgs> Vt then the RdsOn begins affects the voltage proportionally yet for diodes and BJT'S due to thermal sensitivity, they need a knee current around 1mA or so to use as a rough voltage reference of of 0.6 while 0.7 is commonly used for higher current at some fraction like 5% of rated current otherwise specified as Vf at rated current (not abs max). LEDs are often better than Zeners espec. If higher power rated. But FETs are good for low for uA. Voltage ref.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the purpose of the MOSFET highlighted in yellow?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI6oA3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Consider the above as an equivalent, which is simulate-able here in CircuitLab.  D1 is shown externally but is generally internal to the MOSFET.  V2 is a triangle voltage source which starts at 0V, peaks at 5.0V, and goes back down to 0.0V a few times, just to illustrate applying a voltage from 0-5V to the components. The result is this:

[image: Simulation Results]

Orange trace is the applied voltage, 0-5V.

Blue trace is the voltage (or "bias") of the Vout node.

Notice that the blue trace does not increase right away - it stays near 0V until the supply voltage reaches about 2.1V, then begins to increase.  Then, when it does start increasing, it's *slope is not the same as the applied voltage*.

This is due to the \$\text{V}_{\text{GS-th}}\$ or "voltage-gate-source threshold" of this particular MOSFET, which is about 2.1V.  Meaning, the MOSFET starts to "turn on" when the \$\text{V}_{\text{GS}}\$ "voltage gate-to-source" is about 2.1V.

Initially, the MOSFET's Source pin is at zero volts, and the Gate voltage is rising. But when it hits 2.1V and starts conducting between Drain and Source, this *increases* the Source voltage, which *decreases* the conduction.  So this effectively automatically limits *how conductive* the MOSFET can be.

This phenomenon is otherwise known as a constant-current source.  Because, when more than 2.1V is applied to it, the MOSFET will conduct just enough current to keep the \$\text{V}_{\text{GS}}\$ voltage at 2.1V - regardless of what the load actually is.

For this H-bridge circuit, the MOSFET is simply applying a small current to the MODE pin, to ensure that it is NOT at 0V nor Vdd but somewhere inbetween.  Anything the user externally applies to the MODE pin will be passed straight through.

*Why this constant-current source and not a simple resistor divider?*  Because resistors have a linear effect on the bias voltage, and this source is non-linear.  As the MODE pin is driven lower and lower (even below 0V) the MOSFET will actively conduct *more* to maintain it's \$\text{V}_{\text{GS}}\$, working to disallow negative MODE pin voltages - something a resistor can't do.

Also, constant-current sources are good for charging capacitors.  The rate at which capacitor voltage increases (with resistance) is *exponential*, but the rate when driven from a constant-current source is *linear*.  So many capacitor-timing circuits utilize a constant-current source to make the charging time linear.

Comment: It is not constant current with anything rather constant voltage for current over a range of sub-threshold gate voltage = Vds  thus Vds=Vt.. If there was a source resistor then it could be a current source